# Написав его так(,) как надо

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Исправьте-таки в следующем предложении ошибки, написав его так(,) как надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) *Исправьте-таки в следующем предложении ошибки, написав его **так, как надо**.*

СПП  с придаточным **образа действия**. Местоименная связь: ***так...как***.

(2) *Исправьте-таки в следующем предложении ошибки, написав его **как надо**.*

**Цельное** сочетание с подчинительным союзом  **[по Розенталю](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146).**  ***Как надо*** —  это *правильно*, оборот имеет значение **одного** слова.